# Ejecutar un código JS desde PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Ya se que hay varios posts, pero no veo cual es mi error. Tengo mi código en php y hay un momento en el quiero sacar un alert, este es mi código.

```
if ($filas>0) {
    header('Location: FormularioPropuesta.html');
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("hello!");</script>';
}
```

Así como está ahora no se me ejecuta el alert y no tengo claro si es error conceptual o de sintaxis.

¡Salud!

Comment: Porque ejecuta location y se mueve a destino, no va a hacer nunca el alert, tendrías que ponerlo en el destino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que en el momento que se ejecuta `header()` ya no llega a tu `echo` e incluso si pusieses tu `header()` después seguirías teniendo el mismo problema.

Recuerda que PHP se ejecuta en el servidor y JavaScript en el navegador, no es recomendable mezclarlos de esa forma.

Para hacer lo que plantes, te recomendaría hacer el redireccionamiento desde JavaScript:

```
<script>
 alert("hello!");
 window.location = 'FormularioPropuesta.html';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Después del `header('Location')` no puedes meter nada, porque todo lo que pongas después, se pierde.

Deberías tener 2 scripts, index.php y página2.php

en `index.php`

```
header('Location: pagina2.php')
```

y en `pagina2.php`

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("hello!");</script>';
```

Otra cosas es que quieras pasar un parámetro por GET hacia la segunda página, entonces el código quedaría así:

en `index.php`

```
header('Location: pagina2.php?param=elparametroquequierapasar')
```

y en `pagina2.php`

```
if(isset($_GET['param'])){
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$_GET['param'].'");</script>';
}
```